# Game of two players on table $20 \times 20$

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

**Game of two players on table 20X20:**

Player one is starting the game.
Each turn he can put red stone on any point $(i,j)$ such that there isn't another stone on $(i,j)$ and there isn't another red stone place on the table in distance of $\sqrt{5}$ (Euclidean distance) from $(i,j)$.

Player two in his turn place blue stone everywhere he want, as long as there isn't another stone placed there already.
The goal of player one is to put as many red stones as he can, and for player two the goal is to reduce as much as he can the amount of red stones placed by player one.

**The question:**

How many red stones Player one can assure he will be able to place in the end of the game? what is the invariant condition and Player one's strategy?

**What I've tried so far:**

I'v noticed that distance $\sqrt{5}$ are equivalent to the distance that horseman can play in chess. Also, if I didn't make any mistake, I found out that if the game is on table $3 \times 3$ or $4 \times 4$, then Player one can put at least $4$ red stones, and can't assure better result.

Comment: @Andreas Red stones can be placed on adjacent tiles. The restriction is that they cannot be placed on tiles that are a knight's move apart.

Comment: Player one at first put stone on the middle point (2,2) so he isn't block any other points. No matter what player two will do, in the second turn of player one he will be able to put antoher red stone. Then I continue with the simulation and I managed to place 4 red stones.

Comment: You will need to examine at least $6 \times 6$ boards to get a true feel for how the $20 \times 20$ board plays out. The edge cells adjacent to each corner block Player 1 from playing in the 2nd edge cell from the corner on the other side, and vice versa. For $5 \times 5$ boards or smaller, these cells for each corner overlap, which changes the game play. You also might need to go higher than $6 \times 6$ to appreciate the impact that edge cells that are more than $2$ away from a corner have on the game.